# Codeigniter. How to get and display data from datatables into modal when press button using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, modal-dialog

Hi i've been stack here for almost 3 days. I want to get and display data(from their respective primary key) into modal. when i click the button view details it always refreshing and the modal won't display. SO please someone help me with this problem

Controller:

```
public function eventdetails($event_id)
{
$this->load->model("event_models");
$data['results'] = $this->event_models->eventdetails($event_id);
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Views (Datatables):

```
 <!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="card-title">EVSU</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body">
          <table id="manageMemberTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
         
         
         


            <thead>
            <tr>
             <th>Event Title</th>
             <th>Start date</th>
             <th>Status</th>
             <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        
              
            <tr>
              <?php foreach ($all_events as $list): ?>



              <td><?php echo $list->event_title; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $list->start_date;?></td>
              <td>Ongoing</td>
              <td><button name="get" id="<?php echo $list->event_id ?>" 
      class="btn btn-block btn-secondary btn-sm get" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" > View Details </button></td>
      
      

            
            </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
          
            </tfoot>

          </table>
        </div>
      </tbody>
        <!-- /.card-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.card -->

      
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
   <!-- /.row -->
   </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Modal where data will be diplay:

```
       <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria- 
       labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align: left;">Event Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
     <img src="assets/css/evsub.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

     <div class="card-body" id="load_data">
   
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
         <tr>

          <th></th>
       <th></th>  
       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       

       <tr>

      <td>Event Title:</td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>



      <tr>
      <td>Event Details:</td>
     <td></td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>When:</td>
   <td>march 13 2020 - march 15 2020</td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
   <td>Venue:</td>
    <td>Gym</td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Course:</td>
      <td>Information Technology</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>Year Level:</td>
     <td>4th year</td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
     <td>Sponsor:</td>
       <td>Evsu</td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>School Year & Semester:</td>
         <td>2019-2020 2nd sem</td>
           </tr>

        </tbody>
        </table>
          </div>
             <p class="card-text"></p>
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>">  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
    >Join</button> 
    </a>
     </div>
  
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
       </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
      <!-- /add mmebers --><!-- /.modal -->
      <!-- /add mmebers -->
      <!-- edit member -->
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#manageMemberTable').on('click', '.get', function(){  
       var event_id = $(this).attr("id");  
     
       $.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Events/eventdetails/"+event_id,
            method:"POST",  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  

                 
                 $('#userModal').modal('show');
                 $('[name="event_title "]').val(data.event_title);  
                 $('#event_desc').val(data.event_desc);  
                 $('#event_id').val(event_id);  
                  
            } 
           
      
            })  

            });
                });
```

Comment: Can we see the script somewhere? If your script is reaching the AJAX part, you can check your network tab in developer tools to see if there is something wrong with the called page (eventdetails).

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a frontend problem (such that the request is not sent as expected), or a backend problem (such that the proper data is sent to the backend, but not processed as expected)?

Comment: add  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` above codes of Ajax

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to use ajax..i just want when i press the button there would be modal popup it will display the selected data from table. but it always refreshing when i use this <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('Events/eventdetails/'.$list->event_id); ?>"><button name="get" id="get" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"  >
               View Details
              </button></td></a>

Comment: it already can get the data now the remaining problem is to display the data from ajax into my modal table in <td> tag

Comment: yes sir. it will display in modal at <td> tag

Comment: i've already update my post sir. the one i'm currently using

Comment: @Jade Brosas have my answer solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Your View with Data Tables:-**

```
<td>
<input type="button" value="View Detail Event" id="<?php echo $list->event_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info view_event" />
</td>
```

**Bootstrap Modal Code:-**

Place this Bootstrap Modal Code before the closing  Tag in your View File where data is being displayed with view Details Button.

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">View Full Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="your_modal_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

**JQUERY AJAX Code:-**

put this after Bootstrap Modal Code but before closing  Tag in Your View File.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.view_event').click(function(){  
       var event_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url : "<?php echo base_url('ControllerName/get_data_in_modal') ?>", 
            method:"POST",  
            data:{event_id:event_id},  
            success:function(data){
            //alert(data);  
             $('#your_modal_detail').html(data);  
             $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
</script>
```

**Controller Code:-**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ControllerName extends CI_Controller {

public function get_data_in_modal(){
      $event_id = $this->input->post("event_id");
          
          $this->load->YourModelName();
          
 $data['events'] = $this->YourModelName->getDatainModal($event_id);
$this->load->view('eventsinModal',$data);

  }
}
?>
```

**Modal Code:-**

```
<?php

class YourModelName extends CI_Model {

function getDatainModal($event_id){

        return $event = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('event_id'=>$event_id))->row_array();   
        }   
}
?>
```

**Create in View folder eventsinModal.php :-**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-bordered"> 

    <div class='row col-md-12'>
     <div class='col-md-6'>
           <tr>
             <td width="30%"><label>Event Title</label></td>  
             <td width="70%"><?php echo $events["event_title"];?></td>  
          </tr> 
        </div>
  <div class='col-md-6'>       
          <tr>
             <td width="30%"><label>Event Start Date</label></td>  
             <td width="70%"><?php echo $events["start_date"];?></td>  
          </tr>
       </div>   
       </div>

</table>
</div>
```